# How to make cloaks cut-proof

Tags: clothing

I need a reliable material to make cloaks really resistant to blade cuts but still vulnerable to impact and therefore able to be penetrated by thrusting attacks.

Edit: the cloak being just a cloak doesn't protect much the wearer so if you get hit with a blade sliding in on your back or your arm the cloak is not damaged but your skin or clothes underneath are bruised or split.

Thrusting forces like an arrow or pointy knife can still penetrate the cloak.

Technology level doesn't matter as long as we do go into fanta scientific stuff

Comment: Stab proof or cut proof? In current engineering terms the approaches are very different.

Comment: "Resistant to blade cuts" - do you mean that the cloak itself will survive the attack, or that it protects the wearer? Those are two separate things.

Comment: What do you mean by "primarily of one material"? Is there a particular reason it's not allowed to have more?

Comment: @Cadence mostly for simplicity reasons

Comment: Any limitations on tech-level?  And, when you say "thrusting forces can still penetrate the cloak", do you mean the actual *force* (like thwacking someone with a hammer), or that stabbing someone with a narrow rapier or dirk would pierce through the cloak?

Comment: normal cloak especially medieval cloak can survive or withstand sword cut already, as long its not rigid or it keep swaying and not thin. not so much against stabbing but theres a way to counter it, and pretty much the wearer still get hurt despite the cloak is fine like you want. if its not clear enough.

Comment: have you ever tried to cut certain soft plastic packaging materials with scissors and it seems like no matter how you do it, it just won't cut?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have just described chainmaille.

It's extremely resistant to cuts.

It leaves the wearer vulnerable to impact damage.

It can be penetrated by pointy thrusts that get through/between the rings and force them apart.

A full cloak made of chainmaille would be really heavy, but "lightweight" was not a specified criterion! However, you can get the same kinds of benefits just by weaving metallic threads, which need not be as thick as chainmaille rings. And you can keep most of the benefits while reducing weight and stiffness further by blending metallic threads with normal cloth.

Comment: Please check Maille Artisans, Trull lovely designs.

Comment: "You have just described chainmaille"... my thoughts *exactly* . Although I'm not sure it necessarily has to be heavy. You'll get most of the desired cut protection from larger rings of thin wire. I believe increased weight (thicker wire, smaller rings) mostly increases resistance to penetration.

Comment: "I believe increased weight (thicker wire, smaller rings) mostly increases resistance to penetration" - only to a certain extent. Even heavy mail properly rivited together was still vulnerable to bodkin pointed arrows. Plate armour evolved to deal with this sort of threat, and using fluted or sculpted parts to deflect thrusts and blows from swords and pole arms.

Answer (score 12):

The material you're looking for is simply wool.

Rather you would need thick woollen fabric. Wool is generally strong enough to take a cut from a sword without much damage and there have been historical reports of soldiers in the 18th century being able to take sword cuts through their woollen great cloaks ([YouTube video discussing this point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQDr13TyLJ8)).

Woollen cloaks have also been used as a weapon, at least for duelling and self-defence, in the Italian fencing tradition. The image below is a plate from the fencing manual of Giacomo di Grassi, [a translation of which is linked to here](https://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Giacomo_di_Grassi#Rapier_and_Cloak), and shows the cloaks being used as shields to block incoming attacks. There are also several other manuals that touch on cloak and sword as well as cloak and dagger (with the cloak used in a similar way as with the sword).

[image: Plate of Cloak and Sword from di Grassi]

Comment: This answer deserves to be higher: we greatly underestimate the many strengths of wool as a material.  A nice video that touches on some of them: [Lindybeige, *A point about cloaks*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yN8cYd3poIk).

Comment: Very much this. The question is basically describing normal cloaks.

Answer (score 10):

There are two modern products for you to consider.

- Cut proof gloves
- Lockable cargo straps

Both have much the same approach, steel threads are woven into the material. This leaves you with a stiffer cloth than you'd normally expect, but with it you get resistance to sharp edges. For the former it's to prevent accidents, for the latter it's to prevent malice, but the effect is the same.

However neither will provide much protection against a sharp point, and negligible protection against impact, only a cutting edge is protected against.

Comment: Any idea what tech level would be required for this?  Presumably there are two main things required — metallurgy for the steel wire (or some sufficiently good alternative wire), and then the weaving tech required for incorporating it into the fabric?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine weaving is very basic, making fine steel wire usable like thread is going to be industrial age

Comment: Wire drawing a a blacksmith skill, so pre-industrial  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire#History  but the industrial revolution would have greatly reduced the cost.

Comment: This is what I thought of immediately.  I did some quick googling to see if you could make wire fibers easily or with a gimmick but couldn't find anything.  Steel wool is made by shaving metal, which could possibly be believable.

Answer (score 2):

**If it is just the cloak that has to survive**

Make it out of a really, really sticky material; something like a gelatine or a really tacky dough. A sword goes through, and the cloak closes again behind it without losing any structural integrity. Cover it with some dust (flour) so it does not stick to everything else, only to itself.

It probably would not last very long; it is liable to breakage if someone were to step on the end, but it could be an interesting sort of substance to explore.

Comment: Are there any dough-like substances that will form sheets the size of a typical cloak without tearing under their own weight?

Comment: @Cadence I suppose pasta dough, but reinforcing it with vertical wires. A sword may not cut the wires but instead follow them as it's less resistance. I was just spitballing though, the question is not science-based so you could imagine a material with these properties.

Answer (score 2):

Weave the cloak from [Ballistic nylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_nylon) or [Kevlar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevlar).

Their joint properties of being tough, resistant to abrasion and cutting, and retaining reasonable flexibility are why they are currently used for things like motorcycle jackets, or protective trousers for when using chainsaws.

Obviously, a sharp blade used repeatedly in the same spot will eventually cut through - but, by that point, it's no longer going to be a particularly sharp blade.

Comment: Kevlar is easily cut, the reason we use it for motorcycle gear is that it doesn't break easily.

Comment: @Separatrix: I think Kevlar is *part* of what cut-resistant gear is made of for ice sports, where people are flying around with sharp blade on their feet.  e.g. https://www.frederictonspeedskating.com/equipment-for-club-programs says participants must have a neck guard and "It must be made of Kevlar, Dyneema or ballistic nylon".  e.g. https://www.ilovespeedskating.com/product-category/protective-gear/cut-resistant/.  But perhaps calling cut-proof gear "Kevlar" is an east-coast-Canada misnomer that I heard when I used to skate; Fredericton is one of the local meets I used to go to.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it's always more complicated than you think. "Kevlar" and all its variants are easily cut by scissors, or a knife point first for example. A kevlar vest is no protection against a knife wielding opponent. However lacking a point or a cutting pair (scissors), say an edge impact from a sword or ice skate blade it won't break, it will however cut if there's a lateral action under the pressure of a blade. I expect the gear you used often had to be replaced when it showed surface damage? So it is kevlar and it does provide the necessary protection, but for a limited number of contacts

Comment: @Separatrix:  In speed skating, actual blade -> person contact is so rare that I've only seen it maybe once ever. 2-person crashes usually manage to keep the blades away from each other.  We wear cut-proof gear just in case, especially neck guards because a sliced neck could be lethal. And since you want gloves anyway, might as well require cut resistant ones. These days the requirement have increased to a cut-proof liner under your skin-suit, but back in my day it was just a neck guard and gloves. Plastic shin guards (soccer style) and fiberglass skate boots stop blades at ice level.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the armor worn by the Mongol warriors who swept across Europe. They rode lightly framed ponies for speed and agility hence heavy armor was not an option.

I believe layered/laminated woven silk was their solution. Silk is very light and very strong.

My friend who does autopsies involving a lot of sharp objects uses quite light gloves that are interwoven with fine tungsten thread.

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out !

Answer (score 1):

What kind of cloak is it ? If it is a deceiptive cloak then you probably can add a layer of magic to make the person who try to cast any spell or physically cut miss it by bind the magic code with the cloak.